# How do I design different kinds of adapters that share a lot of code?

Tags: java, spring, oop

My Java Spring system reads the same kind of data from a variety of other systems. I'd like to hide the detail which type of system is connected, from the rest of the code. In an ideal world, with single-class adapters that differ a lot from each other, there is a simply solution for this, with the factory pattern:

[image]

In reality however, the adapters are composed of many classes that interact. Some adapters deal with different variants of the same data transfer protocol, and share most of the code, with only tiny variations three layers further down the class hierarchy:

[image]

What's the best way to design this kind of adapter? Should the Adapter Factory implement some sort of builder pattern that makes all decisions and assembles the Adapter piece by piece? Should I remove the Adapter Factory completely and let the Adapter itself make all the decisions, passing all criteria down the hierarchy to where they are needed? Is there some sort of Spring autowiring that would support me in choosing the right sub-dependencies as I move down the code tree?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `class`, be is `abstract` or not, with the shared code being inside methods that are marked as `final`, so they cannot be overriden. Then, derive from this class different subclasses to implement the differences between adapters and, as a result you can rest assured that the code that should be the same will indeed be shared among each objects that instantiate your adapter class or subclasses, but, at the same time this will allow you to customize the differences between the subclasses.

If the adapter code is not to be changed, but the classes it is to use vary, then use generics https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics to specify what tools the adapter instances are to use and make sure that you have something like

```
<T extends SomeClass>
```

which will specify what the base class is of the generics you are to use.

Comment: Works well when each adapter is a single class. But in my case, that would lead to adapter classes with thousands of lines of code and blurred responsibilities. How do I efficiently design the distinction if the adapters are spread across several classes.